# Screen does not reconnect after suspend

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

I've been using screen for a few days now. I usually want to launch a computation on a more powerful machine which can be reached only through ssh. Since the computations tend to be quite lengthy, I want to be able to launch the computation and reconnect to it later to see the result/status.

The solution which has been proposed is using `screen`. This seems to work for a short while, but if I do one of the following

- change the network (wired to wifi)
- suspend my computer

then `screen -r` does not work. If I type `screen -r` I see the list of screens. When trying to reconnect with `screen -r PID:host...` I see an error containing `broken pipe` and I simply cannot resume the process.

Is this normal? Are there any other solutions (which do not require installing something on the server) so that I could launch a process and connect to it even after I change the network or shut down my computer?

Comment: It seems to me you are running an SSH session in screen, rather than running screen on the server itself. I would suggest to make an ssh connection first, then start screen, en then start your program. If your connection disconnects, then at least screen (and your program inside) keeps running. Making a new SSH connection allows youto reattach to your screen session.

Comment: @Sander Yes, the guys from the computer department helped me sort that out. I was running screen on my machine instead of the server...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was a naive question with a simple answer.

In fact, I was running the screen on my machine and then going through ssh to the server. You need to do it the other way around. Connect to the server and run screen there to keep the computation going after loss of connection.